# How to disable security for a specific controller method in NestJS/Swagger?

Tags: authentication, methods, swagger, overriding, nestjs

I am using NestJS with Swagger Module to produce the equivalent API Spec.
Is there a way to disable security for a specific controller method, while having marked the Controller class as requiring authentication?
Example:

```js
// apply bearer auth security to controller
@ApiBearerAuth()
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  // How can **getHello** method be made public???
  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

I am looking for a more intuitive way compared to the straightforward one where each controller method should be mark with security except for the public ones....

I have tried using `@ApiOperation({ security: [] })` without any result. It still get's the security definition from the controller class

Answer (score 2):

It seems after all that this has been already discussed and will not be implemented: github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1319

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a `swagger/apiSecurity` metadata decorator and update the method's security after the swagger document is created:

```js
const PublicAuthMiddleware = SetMetadata(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
const PublicAuthSwagger = SetMetadata('swagger/apiSecurity', ['public']);

export const Public = () => applyDecorators(
  PublicAuthMiddleware,
  PublicAuthSwagger,
)
```

And wherever you create your swagger document (for me it was the `main.ts`):

```js
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);

Object.values((document as OpenAPIObject).paths).forEach((path: any) => {
    Object.values(path).forEach((method: any) => {
        if (Array.isArray(method.security) && method.security.includes('public')) {
            method.security = [];
        }
    });
});
```

(source:  https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/892#issuecomment-1069549916)

Answer (score -1):

`@ApiBearerAuth()` support Controller and function. You should put `@ApiBearerAuth()` into what function you need

```
// apply bearer auth security to controller
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  // How can **getHello** method be made public???
  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @ApiBearerAuth()  <---- here
  @Post()
  createHello(): string {
    return this.appService.createHello();
  }

}
```

Comment: As I stated in my question, I already know the method-specific way. I wanted to know whether an "exclude method from class" approach is possible